# AttributeError: module 'pyspark.sql.types' has no attribute 'ListType'

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I defined a UDF and it will return 3 values. 1 is an integer value. 2 is a float value and 3 is a list.

```
mylist = [8,9.5,10,11,12]
def Calculat(mylist):
  x = mylist[0]
  y = mylist[1]
  list = mylist[-3,-2,-1]
  return x, y, list
```

Then I want to run this to define 3 types with this code

```
func = F.udf(lambda x: calculate(x), T.StructType(
        [T.StructField("val1", T.IntegerType(), True),
         T.StructField("val2", T.FloatType(), True),
         T.StructField("val3", T.ListType(), True)]))
```

But I get this error

AttributeError: module 'pyspark.sql.types' has no attribute 'ListType'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ListType is not available in Pyspark. You will need to change to `ArrayType`, which always needs a defined type of the elements.

```py
func = F.udf(lambda x: calculate(x), T.StructType([
    T.StructField("val0", T.IntegerType(), True),
    T.StructField("val1", T.FloatType(), True),
    T.StructField("val2", T.ArrayType(T.IntegerType()), True),
]))
```

Also a small thought on my side. I really like the UDF decorator, when developing UDF functions. I really like this approach because it makes the code look much cleaner in my opinion. Your code would look as follows:

```py
returnType=T.StructType([
    T.StructField("val0", T.IntegerType(), True),
    T.StructField("val1", T.FloatType(), True),
    T.StructField("val2", T.ArrayType(T.IntegerType()), True),
])

@F.udf(returnType=returnType)
def calculate(mylist):
  x = mylist[0]
  y = mylist[1]
  list = mylist[-3,-2,-1]
  return x, y, list
```